# Webpack ngTemplate-loader won't include my templates into the bundle: how to debug?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angularjs-ng-template, webpack-html-loader

I use webpack to build an angular project. My webpack configuration is copied from another project, where it works successfully.

But in my project it won't include .html templates into the resulting javascript bundle.

Here's the part of webpack configuration of interest:

```
const webpackConfig = {
    ...
    module: {
        ...
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: "body",
                template: "app/index.html",
                filename: "index.html"
             })
        ],
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: `${path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html")}`,
                loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`, "html"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The scaffold of my project is as follows:

```
├── app
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   ├── auth.service.js
│   │   │   └── user.service.js
│   │   ├── footer
│   │   │   └── footer.html
│   │   ├── header
│   │   │   └── header.html
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── home.html
│   │   │   └── home.module.js
│   │   ├── navigation
│   │   │   └── navigation.html
│   │   ├── right_sidebar
│   │   │   └── right_sidebar.html
│   │   └── util
│   │       ├── util.module.js
│   │       └── util.service.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── shared
├── assets
├── package.json
├── gulpfile.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

In `index.html` I say:

```
<div id="header" ng-include="'/components/header/header.html'"></div>
```

and header template is not included in the resulting `app.<hash>.js` bundle. How to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html-loader` not parsed `ng-include` attribute by default. So, you need to pass `attrs` [parameter](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) to loader:

```
html?attrs[]=div:ng-include
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it didn't help. I guess, "html&attrs" is a typo error, it should be "html?attrs"? Still, doesn't work with '?'.

Comment: Yep, it should be '?'. You excluded `index.html` from '*.html' loader - this file processed with other loader?

Comment: Ah, you're right! I excluded it as new `ngTemplate-loader` curses about index.html. I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject `app.<hash>.js` and friends into index.html. So, as it's excluded, I can't use `ng-include` on it or I have to manually require all the templates, `ng-included` in it in `app.js`?

Comment: As described in `HtmlWebpackPlugin ` docs ( https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin ) `template` parameter supports loaders: `ngtemplate!./index.html`

Comment: I found a reference to why I excluded index.html from loading with `html-loader` version 2: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/212. So, do you suggest that I keep `index.html` excluded for html loader, but should set `template: "ngtemplate!app/index.html"`  in HtmlWebpackPlugin configuraiton?  Sorry, I can't figure out the function of ngTemplate-loader from its documentation. It does something before invoking `html-loader`, but I don't understand, what.

Comment: You are right, you must add loader to `template` parameter.

Comment: Loaders are applying from right to left, so `html-loader` will be first. `ngtemplate-loader` putting loaded template into `$templateCache` in order to angular can render it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bob Sponge.

Comment: NP. Seems I've missed `html-loader`: `template: "ngtemplate!html!app/index.html"`

Comment: When I said in `HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "ngtemplate!html!app/index.html", ... })`, it started to curse about `html-webpack-loader` `ReferenceError: window is not defined` again. I guess, I'd better manually `require` ng-includes of `index.html` in `app.js` - no big deal and this solution works. Though, It curses about images, referenced in templates. But that's another story

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Seems the issue is with single quotes. " 'someting.html' " will not be touched by html loader. But "something.html" will be. In this case something.html will be in the app.js but ng-include will not work!